# Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link not working for empty ASP.NET project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I want to know what the minimum requirements are for Browser Link to work.

I have a fresh install of the Windows 8.1 Preview, with the Visual Studio 2013 Preview and Web Essentials.

I have been able to get Browser Link working with a new ASP.NET SPA project, but when I created a new ASP.NET Empty project, added an index.html page and run with Internet Explorer 11 set as the default it did not work.

The Browser Link tooltip kept saying `No Browser is connected`. I've also tried with other browsers, including Chrome, with no success.

I read in other places that the `web.config` file must have the `debug` set to 'true' which it was.

Any suggestions? Maybe I'm misunderstanding some dependencies or use cases of the new feature.

Answer (score 5):

Have you added `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = "true" />` in web.config? Browser Link doesn't work for HTML pages by default setting.

Please check "Known Browser Link issues for Preview" section in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx).

By the way, it didn’t work just adding it in web.config.  I made an empty aspx page.  I started debug for the aspx page first, and then type the url of the html page, so Browser Link works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Browser Link makes use of [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) under the covers, so that has a few dependencies:

1. A relatively modern browser (almost anything from IE 7 and onwards)
2. JavaScript to be enabled on the browser
3. [The ability for the the browser to talk back to the computer running VS, which is acting as a server. Firewalls/proxies could hurt this.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-546)
4. **My gut** says that since it is SignalR, which has a server, that the server needs to run ASP.NET & thus needs the run time bits their to work. This could be your issue.

In addition the `web.config` file needs to have

1. [Debug set to true](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Kazuhiko, you need static files to be processed by IIS.  This can be done by adding:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

to your `web.config`.  So, for example, my `web.config` file for a TypeScript project looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Enable BrowserLink -->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8.1 with Update and Visual Studio 2013.

I did need:

- debug="true" in the web.config
- running .NET 4.0 or greater.
- running razor v2 or greater.
- then to restart Visual Studio (this was the gotcha for me).

I did NOT need:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
    <add name="Browser Link for HTML" ... />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2013.  Click the Browser button down arrow to choose browser(s)
1. [image: Click the Browser button down arrow to choose browser(s)]

2. [image: Select your Browser(s) and then click the Browse button. You also can select the browser size.] Select your Browser(s) and then click the Browse button. You also can select the browser size.

Click "View" on the main menu..  Click Other Windows and then go to Browser Link Dashboard

3. [image: Click Other Windows and then go to Browser Link Dashboard]
   The dashboard should appear under the Solution Explorer window. If not click Reset Window Layout under the Windows tab on the main menu.
4. [image: Notice the Project name and the number of connections based on the browsers you choose]  Notice the Project name and the number of connections based on the browsers you choose

5.[image: Click the down arrow next to the browser you selected to see options to edit your contents in your browser - Design, Inspect or Save]  Click the down arrow next to the browser you selected to see options to edit your contents in your browser - Design, Inspect or Save

6.[image: Your URL points to your web site. You can type that directly into the browser for each browser you have.]  Your URL points to your web site. You can type that directly into the browser for each browser you have.

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me, however I found this:

From http://itq.nl/short-visual-studio-2013-browser-link-tip/

```xml
<handlers>
  <!-- needed for browser link and html pages-->
  <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
       type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>

<!-- needed for browser link and html pages-->
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">     
</modules>
```

I needed both sections for it to work.

I noticed after this that clicking the refresh button sometimes asked if I want to stop debugging. I just clicked yes and it seemed to work happily after that